# Difference in returning values outside and inside a callback function for a method

Tags: javascript

I have a method that executes the following function, yet I noticed I can use `return` in both ways.

Once inside the function:

```
this.tasks.forEach(function(task) {
    return task.completed = true;
});
```

Once outside the function:

```
return this.tasks.forEach(function(task) {
    task.completed = true;
});
```

Both times I get the correct result, yet I wonder if there is any difference.

Comment: Here is an example that should make the difference more apparent: `function foo() { return [1,2,3].map(function() { 5; }); }` vs `function foo() { [1,2,3].map(function() { return 5; }); }` vs  `function foo() { return [1,2,3].map(function() { return 5; }); }`. Call each one with `console.log(foo());`.

Comment: The general rule I follow is "if I need to return (something)", then use `return`".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the return statement inside the callback function goes, there is no difference, except for the fact that there is an unnecessary `return` statement in the first example. The return value of the `forEach` callback function is unused.

However, the return statement outside the callback function could make a functional difference, as it will return `undefined` in the function it is run in. `undefined` is the default return value, so you will only notice a difference if there is code after it that is now being skipped. Of course, calling `return` inside the callback will not return the parent function, as your second example will.

#### Excerpt from [the MDN page on `forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

> `forEach()` executes the `callback` function once for each array element; unlike `every()` and `some()`, it always returns the value `undefined`.

Comment: Which one of both examples would be the correct use in your opinion?

Comment: @LoveAndHappiness: None of them. `forEach` doesn't return anything and it doesn't do anything with the return value of the callback. There should be no `return` statement here at all.

Answer (score 1):

They're very different but not in a way that necessarily makes any difference in this case. Having `return task.completed = true` inside the function just has it return true every time, which is ignored by `Array.prototype.forEach`. The other way, the result of forEach is returned, which is always `undefined` (it's a void function).

Comment: It's hard to say that the `return` outside (second case) "does not make any difference"--it may be not be returning anything useful, but it **does** return, which is quite different from not returning, unless it's the last line in the function.